# What do I need to do to make this code work for windows onresize in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problems understanding why the following javaScript is not working when the windows.onresize event is being fired.  I am new to JavaScript and can't see why it will not work.

I am trying to get the screenWidth tag to update to whatever the current width of the screen is, it seems to work onload where the initial value is set but not on onresize and the value stays the same.

Any help greatly appreciated.

The JavaScript is the following:

```
window.onresize = GetWidth();//this code wont update
window.onload = GetWidth();//this code seems to run
```

```
function GetWidth(){
 document.querySelector("screenWidth").textContent=windows.innerWidth; 
}
```

In the webpage I have this HTML:

```
<h1>Current Window size</h1>
<h3>Size is:<screenWidth>whatever</screenWidth>
```

Comment: Should be `window.onresize = GetWidth;`

Comment: You should try with `window.onresize = GetWidth;` or else you give the result of the execution as a handler, not the function itself. Be careful also that resize handlers are fired a lot of times, not just at the end of resize

Comment: Oh thankyou!  I don't know what was thinking! In every other language when I call a function I need the parenthesis so I just did the same here.  Much Regards.

Comment: @BarbaraClarke but you don't want to call the function here. You want the function to be called when event occurs

Comment: Exactly, here you should pass a function reference as the event handler, not the result of the function call :)